# Data inconsistency with h2 database and multithread

Tags: java, database, multithreading, h2

I have a problem when I try to insert multiple data with multithread program. I have a table with autoincrement id. Some times the database returns one id with a **high value**. After insert row, id does not exist in the database. I try with a clean database.

One example:

```
inserted id: 141 - Thread: 21
inserted id: 142 - Thread: 22
inserted id: 143 - Thread: 18
inserted id: 144 - Thread: 20
```

**inserted id: 800 - Thread: 19**

```
inserted id: 146 - Thread: 23
inserted id: 147 - Thread: 21
inserted id: 148 - Thread: 22
inserted id: 149 - Thread: 18
```

When **thread 19** try another insertion, in reference to id 800, it fails for this id. The exception say that this id does not exist. And it really not exist.

I insert and obtain rows ids with next method:

```
  final String insertTerm = "INSERT INTO TERMS (NAME,TYPE) VALUES (?,?)";
  PreparedStatement preparedStatementInsert = this.connection
    .prepareStatement(insertTerm,
            Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
    preparedStatementInsert.setString(1, name);
    preparedStatementInsert.setString(2, type);
    synchronized (this) {
        preparedStatementInsert.executeUpdate();
    }
    ResultSet generatedKeys = preparedStatementInsert
            .getGeneratedKeys();
    if (generatedKeys.next()) {
        id = generatedKeys.getInt(1);
    }
```

***The problem only occurs when more than one thread is used***. What can be happening?

Comment: It is not related to problem but: Why you synchronizing on local variable?

Comment: I synchronize the inserts to try fix the problem, but it not works.

Comment: Move the last 5 lines of the code posted in your question inside `synchronize(this)` and see if it helps.

Comment: I try syncronice the method to. But it not works.

Comment: I never understand people who vote negative without explanation...

Comment: Are you sure you transaction isn't rolled back somehow?

Comment: Yes im sure, I never open one transaction. I try force it with this.connection.setAutoCommit(true);. It is strange that generates such a high id

Comment: Could you post a complete, reproducible test case?